# EIP150 testBlockchain RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ethereumjs

```
ethereumjs-vm > npm run testBlockchain

TAP version 13
# BlockchainTests
# file: ContractCreationSpam test: ContractCreationSpam_d0g0v0_EIP150
ok 1 correct pre stateRoot
ok 2 correct genesis RLP

functional-red-black-tree/rbtree.js:904
  get: function() {
           ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RedBlackTreeIterator.get
```

https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/pull/139/commits/20ae83596266bb240103f81d9115fca8137aa4ab

[Ran to completion with node --stack-size=XXXX] Please refer the commit to package.json in the link above by jwasinger to proceed with npm run testBlockchain with node v8.1.2

Comment: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/pull/139/commits/20ae83596266bb240103f81d9115fca8137aa4ab             [Ran to completion with node --stack-size=XXXX] Please refer the commit to package.json in the link above by jwasinger

Comment: What is your question?